# A noun version of "need"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, mandarin

I'm trying to write a sentence with the phrase "eliminates the need to do sth..." and have gotten as far as “消除作sth..的————”, any suggestions? I don't think 需要or必须are very good choices because they are usually placed near the beginning of the sentence...

Comment: 就用不着做什么 see iciba  1. Credit cards eliminate the need to carry a lot of cash.
有了信用卡就用不着携带很多现金。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) A排除对B的需求 - A eliminates the need for B

(2) A消除对B的需要 - ditto

---

Don't forget to use 对 as 'preposition'.

Comment: You can also use 免除 instead of 排除、消除, and 要求 instead of 需求、需要。

(3) 免除了对B的需求/要求。

Answer (score 0):

use 需求 is better

for example: “需要从源头上消除代写论文的需求” from  新华网

Answer (score 0):

需求；需求量
“需求”虽然有一个“求”，但它可以也经常被作为名词。“需要”实际上也可以做名词。比如说：
“你有没有考虑到我的需要！”
“把人民的需要放在第一位(Not the case for the commies tho...)”
需求更多被放在比较正式的场合。比如做调查时“消费者的需求”。
Don't doubt it. I'm native Chinese haha^^

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest 避免作sth..的需求

消除 doesn't feel right for the context.